# Loading a .PSD file with D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile

Tags: c++, directx-11, psd

I have a strange issue with DX11 and PSD files. I know that it says that DX11 does not support PSD files, however it DOES load RGB PSDs on my development machine. For some reason it ignores alpha channels if present. When I run this same program on another machine, it fails as documented and no texture is loaded.

Has anybody else seen this behavior? Did Microsoft add PSD support in a later update of DirectX that isn't documented, etc?

Both machines are running the June 2010 SDK, the only difference I can see is that I am using Win7 Professional SP1 (which works), and the other machine is Win7 Ultimate no service pack (doesn't work).

Does anybody know of a good way to get PSDs into DX11? Our pipeline is PSD native, so we would prefer to load them straight into memory. At the moment we convert to BMP via an external program, but it is really slow.

Thanks

Comment: Just as a stab in the dark, but it might be because you have a PSD Windows Imaging Component (WIC) codec installed on one machine, but not the other.

Comment: That is exactly what it was. It seems that in my many years of travels on this development machine I have picked up this component without even realizing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Ross Ridge's comment, this is the PSD Windows Imaging Component (WIC) that allows you to read PSD files into DX11 textures. Be aware however that it won't read in the alpha channel, just the RGB of the PSD. This is fine for most purposes.